# Database Design: relate to car's model or trim?

Tags: mysql, database, data-modeling, database-design

I'm re-asking a question that was previously deleted here in SO for not being a "programming question". Hopefully, this is a bit more "programming" than the last post.

First, a few definitions:

- **model** - `2011 Nissan Sentra`
- **trim** - `2011 Nissan Sentra LX`

Generally, a particular vehicle would have a list of, say, available *colors* or *equipment* options. So a `2011 Nissan Sentra` may be available in the following colors:

- Black
- White
- Red

Then, the manufacturer may have made a special color only available to the `2011 Nissan Sentra LX` trim:

- Pink with Yellow Polka Dots

If I were building a car website wherein I wanted to capture this information, which of the following should I do:

- Associate the colors to the model?
- Associate the colors to the trim?
- Associate the colors to the model and trim?

My gut feeling is that associating it to the model would be sufficient. Associating to trim would mean duplicates (e.g. `2011 Nissan Sentra LX` and `2011 Nissan Sentre SE` would both have "Black" as a color). Trying to associate colors to model and trim might be overkill.

Suggestions?

Comment: I would make the color a free-form field, which is pre-populated in the UI with common choices. I think this is how most car web sites do it. The main advantage is that it makes your DB schema much simpler, and keeps your car model/color researchers from going insane.  But it also allows for custom paint jobs that aren't available from the manufacturer at all.

Comment: Can you propose a model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are special cases, as you say, where a manufacturer has made a special color only available to a specific trim, like ***"Pink with Yellow Polka Dots"*** for the ***"2011 Nissan Sentra LX trim"***

and **you want to have those special case stored**, you should choose the 2nd option.

So, your relationships would be:

1 manufacturer makes many models

1 model has many trims

1 trim can have many colors and for 1 colour many trims have it
(so you'll need an association table for this relationship)

```
Manufacturer
    1\
      \
       \N
     Model
       1\
         \
          \N
         Trim          Colour
           1\           1/
             \          /
              \N       /M
              TrimColour
```

With additional information about colours:

One GeneralColour can be named as many Colours by different Manufacturers and
one Manufacturer can "baptize" a GeneralColour with various Colour (names)

```
        Manufacturer         
         1/      1\           
         /         \         
        /N          \        
     Model           \     GeneralColour
       1\             \       1/
         \             \      /
          \N            \N   /M
         Trim           Colour
           1\           1/
             \          /
              \N       /M
              TrimColour
```

---

Thinking more clearly, the extra `Manufacturer-Colour` relationship is not needed:

```
Manufacturer
    1\
      \
       \N               
     Model                 GeneralColour
       1\                     1/
         \                    /
          \N                 /M
         Trim           Colour
           1\           1/
             \          /
              \N       /M
              TrimColour
```

Comment: But the `Black` for the `2011 Nissan Sentra LX` is the same as the Black for the `2011 Nissan Sentra SE`. Storing that `Black` more than once is duplication of data, right?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, `Black` is the same for both those models. `Black` is the same for `Toyota Corolla` too and for `Ferrari Testarosa` (a `Black Ferrari` would be an abomination but lets skip this point). No, because it's not duplication of data. You'll have many `Nissan` models in your tables and many `Black` as well.

Comment: When I say "Black", I'm not referring to the generic color black. I am referring to the very specific kind of black for that vehicle (e.g. the ones with the fancy names like "Midnight Black" and are assigned a specific manufacturer's code). There would be duplication of data, right?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: even in that case, why do you think it's duplication?

Comment: no it still would not be duplication.  as a matter of fact, Midnight Black #4345 will only appear once - proper normalization.

Comment: @Randy: thnx. @Stack: as a matter of fact, I thought about that "Midnight Black" thing and you could add one more `GeneralColour` table that has `1:N` relationship with `Colour` so you can store that `Midnight Black` is just a synonym of (generic) Black.

Comment: ypercube - it would be duplicate data because you would have "Midnight Black" for the "2011 Nissan Sentra LX" and the "2011 Nissan Sentra SE". I already have these "fancy colors" mapped to a generic color (so "Midnight Black" is really just marketing terms for "Black").

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: You also have many `Nissan Sentra` don't you? A `2011 SE` one, a `2011 XL` one, a `2010 SE`. Is that duplicate too?

Comment: "Midnight Black" for the 2011 Nissan Sentra is not the same as the "Midnight Black" for the 2010 Nissan Sentra. At least that is how I see the data. What do you think?

Comment: You will only store `Midnight Black` to table `Colour` (with an FK referencing `Black` at table `GeneralColour` and an FK referencing `Nissan` at table `Manufacturer`). Then at table `TrimColour` you only save an FK that references `Midnight Black`. That's (one point of) what normalization is about. **Your only duplication should be Primary Keys (stored once in their table and duplicated again and again as Foreign Keys in other tables)**.

Comment: Again, "Midnight Black" for 2010 Nissan Sentra is not the same as "Midnight Black" for the 2011 Nissan Sentra. So having 2 "Midnight Black" in this case is not duplication, I think (e.g. very possible that they have the same name, but slightly different RGB values, etc.).

Comment: @ypercube let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1338/discussion-between-stackoverflownewbie-and-ypercube)

Answer (score 2):

If different trims for the same model may have different color options (as you imply) then you should associate the color to the trim, otherwise you will have incorrect/incompatible information.  aka If "pink with yellow polka dots" is associated to the "2011 Nissan Sentra" model then you will incorrectly show it as an option for trims other than LX.

Comment: I think 99% of the time, colors are associated to model. Is it so bad to display "Pink with Yellow Polka Dots" to a non-`2011 Nissan Sentra LX` trim when trying to capture that particular trim's color?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: If you don't mind having a not accurate model, then go ahead and choose the first option (associate the colors to the model). It's not that big difference if you only have a site/database that shows information. If however, a customer can order cars from your site/database, then he may order something that you can't provide.

Comment: ypercube - and if I didn't want a user to potentially order soemthing that can't be provided (e.g. a 2011 Nissan Sentra SE that is color Yellow with Pink Polka Dots), which option should I choose?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the association of the trim to the model; without that, I don't know that you can really properly complete your associations.

Comment: Model can have 0 or more trims. That part is already modeled.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: you completely left out that relationship from your question, and it makes a BIG difference in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As requested in response to my comment...

I would just make 'color' a free-form text field, possibly with a pre-populated drop-down showing current popular colors in the database.  The main advantage is that it makes your DB schema much simpler, and keeps your car model/color researchers from going insane. But it also allows for custom paint jobs that aren't available from the manufacturer at all.

```
manufacturers
-------------
id

models
------
id
manufacturer (FK to manufacturers.id)
model_name   (VARCHAR)

trims
-----
id
model  (FK to models.id)

cars
-------
id
trim   (FK to trims.id)
year   INT
color  VARCHAR
```

Comment: Color has to be a separate table and associated to either model, trim, or both.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: Why does it have to be a separate table? As an academic exercise, I can see the desire to have it as a separate table, but for a real-world application, I think that makes things too complicated. Your users will hate you. :)

Comment: my users would hate me if White was different than white.

Comment: The reason for this is that I've used "White" to simplify the problem. In reality, the White for a 2011 Nissan Sentra is not the same as the White for the 2011 Honda Civic. Remember, these colors all have fancy names (e.g. Midnight Black, Sunset Blue, etc.). It is those colors that I am trying to represent.

Comment: 1. That's an easy problem to solve. 2. Your users are then also going to hate you if they search for 'Pink', but don't see 'Pink with purple polka dots'. Car _shoppers_ usually only care about the primary color of the car. I.e. "blue" vs. "grey", not "navy blue" vs "metalic blue" vs. "gushing blue" vs. "blue crayon", etc.  And the data entry operators are going to hate having to enter the same color for 18 different trims--almost as much as they're going to hate having to research which trims come in which colors. Let the marketing clerk enter the colors at listing time, on an as-needed basis.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: Okay, if you need to represent those colors, then sure, you probably need a separate table. I have to wonder _why_ you need to represent those colors, though? Shoppers don't care. Dealers don't care. The only entity I can think of that cares about that sort of thing is a body shop, and for them that's not nearly enough information.

Comment: Anyway, this is straying from the topic of the question (which is why I posted my suggestion as a comment instead of an answer in the first place).  I'll delete my answer in about 10 minutes or so, to give anyone who cares a chance to read these last comments first.

Comment: @Flimzy: Why delete the answer? It's a valid option. It all depends in how deeply normalized one wants the database to be.

Comment: @ypercube: You convinced me, I'll leave it.

Comment: @Flimzy - let's say that the dealers in my case do care that the generic color Black is called "Midnight Black" for the 2011 Nissan Sentras.

Answer (score 1):

> If I were building a car website wherein I wanted to capture this
>   information

then you'd have to build a logical model that captured that information. (How hard was that?) And that means you have to model these facts.

- Some colors apply to the model.
- Some colors apply to the trim package.
- (And I'll bet I can find a manufacturer where some colors apply to
  the make.)
- (*And* I'll bet that all these colors also have something to do with the year.)

Capturing all the known requirements is one thing. Implementing them is another. Once you understand how the colors actually work,

- you're free to ignore whatever real-world behavior  you want to.

But, as [Dr. Phil](http://www.drphil.com/) often says,

- "When you choose the behavior, you choose the consequences."

Simplifying the known requirements--ignoring the fact that some colors apply only to one or two trim packages--means you design your database to deliberately allow invalid data. Your database might end up with information about a "Pink with Yellow Polka Dots" Nissan Altima, or a "Copper" 2002 Nissan Sentra. (I think Nissan introduced copper in 2004.)

So here's the real question.

- **How much bad data can you tolerate?**

That's always going to be application-dependent. A social media site that collected information about your car color would be a lot more tolerant of impossible color choices than a company that sells touch-up paint.